# ViewPager2 causes crash by confusing two instances of FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am using `ViewPager2` along with `TabLayout` in my app in a fragment (let's call it the main fragment). The pages are fragments themselves, each representing a list of music items by format, e.g. a page for CDs, a page for Vinyls, etc. The `FragmentStateAdapter` holds a list of the formats which are updated by observing a `LiveData` object.

I have added an option for the user to add a format (i.e. page) in a `DialogFragment`, which crashes the app in certain conditions. If it's used when the user opens up a music item - and thus letting the main fragment go through the onPause, onStop, etc. lifecycle stages - and then goes back to the main fragment, and again opens up a music item and adding a new format, the app crashes, and the logcat shows that this happens because **while it gets the number of tabs/pages from a recent updated `FragmentStateAdapter`, the list of formats themselves it goes through are from a `FragmentStateAdapter` of previous lifecycle**. As such, the app crashes when the `TabLayoutMediator` callback for setting the tabs' text hits an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I hope I've managed to explain the problem clearly enough.
If anything is missing, please let me know.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated called");
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserItemsViewModel.class);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ItemListFragmentAdapter(requireActivity(), mType));
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                (tab, position) -> {

//                    Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position);
//                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(listFragmentAdapter.mItems));
                    if (position == 0) {
                        tab.setText("All");
                    } else {
//                        Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position);
//                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + listFragmentAdapter);
                        tab.setText(((ItemListFragmentAdapter)viewPager.getAdapter()).getItemAt(position - 1).getName());
                    }
                }
        ).attach();

    }

class ItemListFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

//        private static final String TAG = ItemListFragmentAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

        private final String mType;
        private AtomicReference<List<FormatItem>> mItems;

        ItemListFragmentAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, String type) {
            super(activity);
            mType = type;
            mItems = new AtomicReference<>();

            mViewModel.getFormatsLD().observe(activity, new Observer<List<FormatItem>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<FormatItem> formatItems) {
                    mItems.set(formatItems);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });
        }




        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "createFragment called");
            if (mType.equals(ARG_COLLECTION)) {
                return CollectionFragment.newInstance(position);
            } else if (mType.equals(ARG_WISHLIST)) {
                return WishlistFragment.newInstance(position);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + this);
            if(mItems.get() != null){
                Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: size - " + mItems.get().size());
            }
            return mItems.get() == null ? 1 : mItems.get().size() + 1;
        }

        FormatItem getItemAt(int i){
            Log.d(TAG, "i: " + i);
            Log.d(TAG, "size: " + mItems.get().size());
            Log.d(TAG, "list: " + mItems.get());
            Log.d(TAG, "getItemAt: " + this);
            return mItems.get() == null ? null : mItems.get().get(i);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I figured it out on my own. The problem was that I've observed the formats `LiveData` from the constructor of the adapter. That made the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to notify that exact instance of the adapter. But the ViewPager has taken the number of pages from an adapter newly constructed in `onViewCreated`. I fixed it by moving the `LiveData` observer to `onViewCreated`, and notifying the adapter currently associated with the ViewPager:

```
 mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserItemsViewModel.class);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ItemListFragmentAdapter(requireActivity(), mType));
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                (tab, position) -> {

                    if (position == 0) {
                        tab.setText("All");
                    } else {
                        tab.setText(((ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).getItemAt(position - 1).getName());
                    }
                }
        ).attach();

        mViewModel.getFormatsLD().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<FormatItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<FormatItem> formatItems) {
                ItemListFragmentAdapter adapter = (ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
                if (adapter != null) {
                    ((ItemListFragmentAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter()).setItems(formatItems);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```